# Bootstrap form-group alignment not proper in IE 11

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have created a Bootstrap 3.3.4 Form, which works perfectly fine in chrome, but in IE 11 the fields disorient. I have tried adding the following tags but no difference. Screenshots below for fields display chrome and IE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
```

**Fields in chrome**
[image: Fields in Chrome]

**Fields in IE**
[image: Field in IE]

Code is as below :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="insert.php" name="frmAdd" method="post">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4>LOSS EVENT</h4>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-xs-2">Loss Event No</label>
          <div class="col-xs-10">
            <textarea name="Loss_No" rows="1" cols="50" class="form-control" readonly>
            </Textarea>
            <br/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-xs-2">Additional Details</label>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <select name='AdditionalDetails' id="AdditionalDetails" class='form-control selectpicker' required>
              <option value="">Select Additional Details</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <label class="col-xs-2">Date of Occurance</label>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="Date_Occurance" value="" class="form-control" readonly>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-xs-2">Date of Discovery</label>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="Date_Discovery" value="" class="form-control" Required>
          </div>
          <label class="col-xs-2">Date of Reporting</label>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div>
              <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="Date_Reporting" value="" class="form-control" Required>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-xs-2">Description of Loss</label>
          <div class="col-xs-10">
            <textarea name="Description_Loss" rows="5" cols="100" class="form-control">
            </Textarea>
            <br/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-xs-2">GL Used</label>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" name="GL_Used" class="form-control">
            <br/>
          </div>
          <label class="col-xs-2">Any Criminal Event</label>
          <label name="CriminalEvent"></label>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <select name='CriminalEvent' class='form-control selectpicker' required>
              <option value="" selected>Select</option>
              <option value="Y">Yes</option>
              <option value="N">No</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-xs-2">Criminal Event Description</label>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <textarea name="CriminalEvent_Description" rows="5" cols="40" class="form-control">
            </Textarea>
            <br/>
          </div>
          <label class="col-xs-2">Rating</label>
          <label name="Rating"></label>
          <div class="col-xs-4">

          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-xs-2">Impact of the Criminal Event</label>
          <label name="Impact_CriminalEvent"></label>
          <div class="col-xs-4">

          </div>
          <label class="col-xs-2">Findings of the Investigation</label>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <textarea name="Findings_Investigation" rows="5" cols="100" class="form-control">
            </Textarea>
            <br/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-xs-2">Lesson Learnt</label>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <textarea name="Lesson_Learnt" rows="5" cols="100" class="form-control">
            </Textarea>
            <br/>
          </div>
          <label class="col-xs-2">Action Plan</label>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <textarea name="Action_Plan" rows="5" cols="100" class="form-control">
            </Textarea>
            <br/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-xs-2">Current Status</label>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" name="Current_Status" class="form-control">
            <br/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-xs-2">Date Closed</label>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" name="Date_Closed" id="datepicker3" class="form-control">
            <br/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <Footer Align="Center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="SubmitButton">Submit</button>
    </footer>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: can you provide the website link

Comment: the webiste is an intranet site just have a jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/soumyar/rxg9ppts/)